# Creating different quotas for specific machines with Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, unix, afp

I've got Ubuntu server 18 running AFP (Netatalk 3.1.12) and avahi dæmon. This takes the role of a time machine server I use with currently one mac. I would like to use this with several other macs, however I want to be able to set quotas-or volume size limits as they are also referred to as-on a per-machine basis.

So basically machine 1 (UUID based identification) is allowed to use 1.75 tB of my time machine disk for time machine backups, machine 2 is allowed 1.25 tB of space, machine 3 is 2 tB, etc etc etc.

I do see `vol size limit` as a parameter in afp.conf however I believe this is a global quota that everyone is forced to obey and is not machine-specific. I am looking for a solution that is machine-specific quotas, whether it's a program i have to run on the mac or a setting on the server.

Please inform me of options and if details are not clear and please note my English is not very good-I actually have a friend write this for me so may be better than my english :P

Current mac backing up-High Sierra

Other macs wanted to back up-Sierra, Mojave, Mountain Lion, Lion, El capitan, Yosemite, would like to really backup from Leopard onward however at current point in time I do not have Leopard available.

Comment: I‘be removed your second question, the site works better with one question per post. You can always ask separate questions if necessary, but please be aware that „would it be better“ questions often get closed as being primarily opinion-based

Comment: @nohillside apologies, will keep that noted

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no option to limit backup size on the client (macOS) side of things. For server-side limits two options come to mind:

- create individual partitions for each Mac to be backed up and size accordingly (on Macs you could also use sparseimages but I don‘t know whether these are available in your setup)
- create individual users on the server for each Mac to backup, and assign disk quotas with whatever Linux tools available

PS: I know that the options listed lack the specific commands. But AD is focused on Apple products so solving Linux side problems is out of scope. If you need help in implementing one of the options it might be better to ask a specific question on {askubuntu,unix}.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you friend, i have ZFS as my hard disk formatting, currently using three 3 tB disks in a raid 0-like strategy. Never tried partitioning so not sure how easy/hard this will be. Would you happen to know? If not I can still ask on one of those sitse

Comment: @leetbacoon Unix/Linux questions should be asked on the appropriate site.

Comment: yes sir, will do that